# firing ssrs report based on a match

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I need to fire this SSRS report only when there is match between `VM Amount` column and `BI amount` column. Does anyone know how we can do this?

Screenshot of the design is below:

[image: Design screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS how to trigger subscription when new data is loaded to database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19777328/ssrs-how-to-trigger-subscription-when-new-data-is-loaded-to-database)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to move your logic to SQL server side to calculate what you need. 
Next, you need to create a subscription without any schedule.
On the end you should to fire your report from the SQL server when VM Amount column and BI amount columns match.

To fire report from server:

> ```
> exec [dbo].[AddEvent] 'TimedSubscription', @EventData;
> ```

Where @EventData is suppscription id (@EventData='be13bfa4-9c36-423f-90b8-bd449bfd7eb3')

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3078/report-launcher-to-run-ssrs-report-subscriptions-on-demand/